# How to round the corner of table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

How to round the table corner without cutting the corners.

```
#DataTables_Table_1 {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #00478f !important;
    border-radius: 40px !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

I use this code but table look like this.

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you please post your `html` as well?

Comment: '<table class="dataTable visualizer-data-table table table-striped no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_1" role="grid" style="width: 551px;"><thead><tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Year: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 163px;">Year</th>class="sorting_1">2018</td><td>6</td><td>9</td></tr><tr role="row"><td class="sorting_1">2019</td><td>10</td><td>7</td></tr></tbody></table>'

Comment: Rather put your html code in you question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your CSS to table tag, I think you added the code for another element:

```
table {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #00478f !important;
    border-radius: 40px !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```